# Switching between data sets in Highcharts/Highmaps

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a chloropleth map of the number of hogs in the U.S. by county.

I have six different data sets (1987, 1992, 1997, 2002, 2007, 2012) representing the USDA agriculture census that is taken every five years.

As of now, each data set lives within its own Highmaps index file. The 2012 index file is here:   http://www.graysonmendenhall.com/pigs/index_2012.html

I want to implement a slider that will allow a user to switch between data sets to see the changes in the data on the map.

I'm pretty new at using Highmaps, Javascript, and XML/CSV/JSON, btw.

But given my limited knowledge, I'm thinking that I need to create XML/CSV/JSON files for each year's data set, then create a call to get those data sets within the index file, then  create some kind of Javascript event linked to the slider so that it switches what data is displaying.

Am I on the right track here? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Indeed, you are on a right track. Create files (I would choose JSON), on index file call AJAX to get files and store them as variables. On slider change event you can update chart with new data set. To do it in Highcharts, simple call: `chart.series[0].setData(dataset_for_year_X);`

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! I'll give it a try and report back on the results.

Comment: Ok, I've tinkered a little with it... I put my data into individual JSON files and have successfully loaded them according to the console. But no data shows up on my map. I think I'm not pushing the data to the map properly. Could that be the problem (or one of them)? I made a jsFiddle that you can see here   http://jsfiddle.net/GKMendenhall/cnTRd/2/

Comment: As I said before, use `setData()`.. like this: `$('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData(data);`. Of course your jsFiddle won't work, because you can't call AJAX accross the domains.