# How can I switch between JSON data sets in HighMaps using setData?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, highmaps

I have a Highmap that's populated with data fetched using getJSON. What I want to achieve is have a button (or dropdown) that allows me to switch between two or more data sets.

I've seen this question asked a few times in different ways (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150399/switching-between-data-sets-in-highcharts-highmaps)), and reading the answers I think have a general idea of what I need to do, but I remain stuck. FWIW I'm a complete novice just trying to make something work for my colleagues, so my mistake might be fundamental or could just be a matter of syntax.

For now to prove to myself that I can make it work I've tried to implement a button that, once clicked, simply switches to a second data set using setData. While the map is displaying correctly, and I know that both JSON files are being loaded, I can't get the switch to work.

Here is my attempt in full: http://jsfiddle.net/osc9m3e7/4/

And the part that I'm sure is incorrect somehow:

```
$('#setdata').click(function() {
Highcharts.mapChart.series[0].setData(data1);
});
```

I'd appreciate any tips to get me on the right track.

Comment: I played around a bit with your fiddle and think it is loading whichever dataset desired. This is in no way a clean and nice way to do it, which is why I am not posting this as an answer. http://jsfiddle.net/osc9m3e7/2/ . Your code was not complete in the fiddle. At least, I could not find the function you posted above anywhere in the fiddle. I think the main problem is that you are not using `setData` on the highchart object you have created, but instead use it on a uninitated Highchart object. Which is why I made the `chart` variable in the fiddle I posted.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My mistake, I posted the wrong fiddle. I have edited the question above.

I have also tried to use setData on the chart itself by giving the chart a variable name, as you suggest in your link, but that doesn't seem to have solved the issue.

Comment: Here is a working example that I was trying to replicate, but it really only uses one data set (which it then alters randomly): http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/members/series-setdata/

Comment: I included your second dataset link in my fiddle and updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/osc9m3e7/5/, and included a simple if/else to switch between the datasets. As you can see in the example you are trying to replicate, it is also manipulating a chart object stored to a variable, namely `chart`. The following; `var chart = Highcharts.mapChart`, is the important part. By assinging `chart` as a variable, you can manipulate its contents.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much! It's all clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably noticed how borders of countries are getting thicker every time you set new data. It happens because the data object is not copied but used directly, so it is modified. To copy specific object you can use for example `slice()` function. Below you can find an example where switching between sets of data works as it should.

API Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4ub0z408/

Comment: I had noticed that and was investigating why it was happening. Your answer arrived at a perfect time. I've implemented the fix, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by ewolden in the comments. My issue was that I wasn't naming the chart, and therefore not able to manipulate it using setData. The working example is now here: http://jsfiddle.net/osc9m3e7/7/

```
var AccessMap = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
...
$('#setdata').click(function() {
AccessMap.series[0].setData(data2);
});
```